# How to make accordion display dynamic information correctly

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I have a database that stores some entries in sections. Each section has multiple subsections and I'd like to create an accordion drop down to display all the sections in a list and when clicking a section then its subsections are displayed.
For example:
Sections 1,2,3 each with their own 2 subsections (1.1, 1.2, 1.3, etc).I want them displayed as 1,2,3 and when I open section 1 for example then the accordion shows me subsections 1.1,1.2 and 1.3. Currently the accordion displays section 1 three times each entry with its own subsection 1->1.1 then 1->1.2 and 1-1.3. This is for the last 2 sections as well.

I'm currently stuck at this which does not display the sections how I want them:

```
String sql = "select * from sections inner join subsections on sections.id_section=subsections.id_section ";
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql);
while (rs.next())
{
    out.println("<div id='accordion-container'>" + "<h2 class='accordion-header'>" + rs.getString("section_name") + "</h2>");
}
while (rs.next()) {
    out.println("<div class='accordion-content'>" + rs.getString("subsection_name") + "</div>" + "</div>");
}
rs.close();
s.close();
con.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logical error in your code there. After the first while ends there's nothing left in rs to drive the second while. I suggest using 2 different variables (sprev scurr) to track if the current section is different from the previous and only when that occurs to close the current section and start another one. First of all initialize the 2 vars with something like 0, and then, in the first while, make the current section scurr = rs.getInt('id_section'). After that check to see if the previous section is different from the current one. If true, check to see if the previous section is not 0 and if true close the section div. Start a new section div right after that (inside the first if) and print out its' name. Outside of the if statements print the code for displaying subsections. Just before ending the current while cycle make the sprev var equal to scurr.

I have prepared an exmple for you bellow:

```
ResultSet srs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM subsections inner join sections on         subsections.id_section=sections.id_section");

//variables for current and previous section ids (initially 0 = non-existent)
int idCurrentSection = 0;
int idPreviousSection = 0;

while (srs.next()) {
    idCurrentSection = srs.getInt("id_section"); //get and save the current section id
//if previous section is equal to current section we skip closing and opening a new     section block and just write the subsection name
    if(idCurrentSection!=idPreviousSection){ //if current section is different from previous section we need to start a new section block
        if(idPreviousSection != 0) //if previous section id is different from 0 we need to close the previous section block
            System.out.println("</div>");
        System.out.println("<div class='section'>"); //open a new section block
    }


    System.out.println("<p>"+srs.getInt("section_name")+"</p>");    //write the new section name

    System.out.println("<div class='subsection'>"); //start a new subsection
    System.out.println("<p>"+srs.getInt("subsection_name")+"</p>"); //write the subsection name
    System.out.println("</div>"); //inchid subsectiunea

    idPreviousSection = idCurrentSection; //previous section is now the current section

   }

System.out.println("</div>"); //careful to close the last section block
```